# How To Show An Intro View For 5 Seconds

Tags: android, view

How is possible show an intro view for 5 seconds, to show after another view?
With this code I will wait for 5 second and after I will see the second view, but never the first.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.intro);
    t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    do{
        t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }while(t1 - t0 <= 5000);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

Comment: Do you want code for splash screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you can do it by splash screen ::**

[this is example](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-loading-welcome-splash-spash-screen-example)